# Pandas get max of sequence

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time, timestamp

I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
index                 status    counting
2018-02-11 10:00:00   close     0
2018-02-11 10:00:01   close     0
2018-02-11 10:00:02   close     0
2018-02-11 10:00:03   open      1
2018-02-11 10:00:04   open      2
2018-02-11 10:00:05   open      3
2018-02-11 10:00:06   close     0
2018-02-11 10:00:07   close     0
2018-02-11 10:00:08   close     0
2018-02-11 10:00:09   open      1
2018-02-11 10:00:10   open      2
2018-02-11 10:00:11   open      3
2018-02-11 10:00:12   open      4
2018-02-11 10:00:13   open      5
2018-02-11 10:00:14   open      6
2018-02-11 10:00:15   close     0
2018-02-11 10:00:16   close     0
2018-02-11 10:00:17   close     0
```

I want to calculate the average duration of consecutive "open" intervall. Either by

- Accessing the index of both the beginning and end of those intervall
  or
- Taking the hightest counting number for each open block ..

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can compare values by `open`, then invert mask by `~` with cumulative sum for groups and filter only `open` rows, last pass to `groupby`:

```
m = df['status'].eq('open')

s = df.groupby((~m).cumsum()[m])['counting'].max()
print (s)
status
3.0    3
6.0    6
Name: counting, dtype: int64
```

If need `mean`:

```
s = df.groupby((~m).cumsum()[m])['counting'].mean()
print (s)
status
3.0    2.0
6.0    3.5
Name: counting, dtype: float64
```

If need minimal and maximal values:

```
df = df.reset_index()
m = df['status'].eq('open')

df1 = df.groupby((~m).cumsum()[m])['index'].agg(['min','max'])
print (df1)
                        min                  max
status                                          
3.0     2018-02-11 10:00:03  2018-02-11 10:00:05
6.0     2018-02-11 10:00:09  2018-02-11 10:00:14
```

**Details**:

```
print ((~m).cumsum())
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     3
4     3
5     3
6     4
7     5
8     6
9     6
10    6
11    6
12    6
13    6
14    6
15    7
16    8
17    9
Name: status, dtype: int32

print ((~m).cumsum()[m])
3     3
4     3
5     3
9     6
10    6
11    6
12    6
13    6
14    6
Name: status, dtype: int32
```